# Protractor - Run a instances to each spec file

Tags: protractor

so, I'm new in the tests world. srsr.

I've somy spec files and I running it 4 instances  for about 10 spec files.

I would like to know if is a good idea to create a instance to run each file?
I know that if I have 10 files, doing it is ok.

But if I have 30 files?
setup 30 instancies, one for each.

is it good idea ?

thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

By instance I assume you are talking about running your tests in parallel. Running tests in parallel is meant to speed up your the time it takes to execute your test suite. How many tests you can reliably run in parallel depends on your setup. At some point, if you have to many tests running in parallel tests will begin to timeout. If 30 instances for 30 tests will reliably run on your machine, then that is what you should do. But it defeats the purpose if tests are timing out from to much stuff going on.